# Expressão regular para e-mail em C++

Tags: c++, regex

Tenho a seguinte expressão regular em uma função de validação de formatos em C++ usando regex, porém ela esta validando formatos fora do padrão que desejo.

> `b[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,4}b\\.[A-Z]{2,4}b`

```
    Email: regex_cpp@net.br Valid
    Email: regex_cpp@terra.com.br Valid
    Email: regex_cpp@hotmail.com.br.net Valid (não pode validar)
    Email: regex_cpp@hotmail.com Valid
    Email: regex_cpp@yahoo.com.br Valid
    Email: regex_cpp@gmail.com Valid
    Email: regex_cpp@bol.com.br Valid
    Email: regex.cpp@bol.com Valid
    Email: reg_ex.cpp@bol.com Valid
    Email: reg_ex.cpp@org.br Valid
    Email: reg_ex.cpp@net.org.br Valid
```

o problema que quero enfatizar é a expressão regular teria que validar somente formatos como:

```
.com
.com.br
.net
.net.br
.org
.org.br
```

e formatos como:

```
 @terra.com.br
 @bol.com.br
 @yahoo.com.br
 @hotmail.com.br
 @hotmail.com
```

ou seja a expressão não deve validar nada depois de .br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de tanto fuçar na net, acabei encontrando uma regex que sirva para ambos os casos tanto na validação e e-mails:

`^[a-z0-9.][a-z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:[.][a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?(?:[.][a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)?`

```
.com 
.com.br
.net.org.br
```

E os formatos

`.com.br.net` são inválidos de acordo com a regex.

Comment: Dei uma reformtada na sua resposta, mas não tenho certeza se ficou legal. Recomendo dar uma revisada nela quanto a isso.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente eu não sei qual o intuito dos *b*, creio se poderia ser o `\b` que delimita as fronteiras da *string*.

Sumindo que [a REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/KBcrD6/2) seja :

```
/[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\.[A-Z]{2,4}/
```

Os `matchs` que você informou também não fecham.

- Creio que esta parte esta duplicada `\.[A-Z]{2,4}`.
- E suponho que esteja usando o modificador `i` (case-insensitive).

Assumindo então que [a REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/KBcrD6/3) seja :

```
/[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}/i
```

Partindo disso o problema que você tem esta no parte `@[A-Z0-9.-]+`, pois apos o `@` note que ele esta pesquisando também pelo `.` o que gera seu erro, pois ele considera como parte de captura o próprio `.com`.

Para resolver isso, pode alterar para `@[A-Z0-9-]+`, contudo vai validar apenas com um ponto `.com` e não `.com.br`. [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/KBcrD6/4).

Para ajustar este problema tera de alterar `\.[A-Z]{2,4}` para `(\.[A-Z]{2,4}){1,2}`. [REGEX](https://regex101.com/r/KBcrD6/5)

Comment: pior que mesmo assim ainda nao esta validando corretamente olhe o codigo estou tentando fazer esta regex funcionar ja faz ums tres dias http://pastebin.com/evVcm7FE usei tambem essa aqui conforme esta no site REGEX const std::regex pattern("[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Z]{2,4}){1,2}"); e mesmo assim ainda nao valida

Answer (score 1):

O problema que você está tendo é que `@[A-Z0-9.-]+` está considerando um ponto, não queremos este comportamento.

Não entendi muito bem os `b`s jogados pela regex da pergunta, mas fazendo alguns testes a regex que melhor caberia para este caso seria:

`^([A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}(\.[A-Z]{2,4})?)$`

Note que `^` no inicio e `$` indicam que queremos strings *exatamente* assim, sem matches parciais.

[Caso de teste](https://regex101.com/r/NzIu0O/1)

Comment: ela ainda continua validando da mesma forma http://pastebin.com/L9rqeqEv

Comment: O seu está `\.[A-Z]{2,4}?(` onde o meu está `\.[A-Z]{2,4}(`, não é esse o problema?

Comment: não pois ja estava assim  \.[A-Z]{2,4}(, e ainda continuava validando formatos como: .com.br.net

Comment: Entendi, atualizei a resposta, você poderia checar novamente por favor?
Não to conseguindo utilizar seu código aqui... Tá dando valid mesmo pra uma string qualquer.

Não tá faltando um return na linha 21 pra começar?