# Regex que valida somente anos normais e bissextos em C++

Tags: c++, regex

Estava tentando fazer validação de anos bissextos usando regex em C++.

Se o usuário digitar `28/02/1900`, ele retornaria válido. Mas se o mesmo digitar `29/02/1900`, ele retornaria erro.

Pesquisando, achei esta regex que compilou, mas não está validando.

```
const std::regex pattern("^(?:(?:31(/)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|(?:Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(/)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2]|(?:Jan|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$|^(?:29(/)(?:0?2|(?:Feb))\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])(/)(?:(?:0?[1-9]|(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep))|(?:1[0-2]|(?:Oct|Nov|Dec)))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$");
```

Tentei simplificar baseado em outra regex para algo como:

```
const std::regex pattern("(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[8|9])[*-. /](0[2]|Feb)[*-. /](19[04|08|12|16])\\d{2,2}"); //dd/mm/yyyy
```

Simplifiquei a partir desta com base na primeira:

```
const std::regex pattern("(0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[8|9]|3[0|1])[*-. /](0[1-9]|1[0|1|2]|Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)[*-. /](19|20)\\d{2,2}"); //dd/mm/yyyy
```

Para concluir estou tentando escrever uma regex que leia ambas mas caso a pessoa digite mais de 29 dias para fevereiro e 29 dias para um ano não-bissexto, ela não deve validar.

Se alguém puder me ajudar ficaria grato.

Comment: Você precisa através de expressões regulares fazer essa conta? Não é melhor fazer uma conta simples não?

Comment: sim queria que o calculo fosse feito somente pela regex validando somente por ela...

Comment: Estou com o @JeffersonQuesado. Parece-me um canhão para matar uma mosca

Comment: Por que você quer validar se uma data é bissexta usando expressões regulares? Isso parece ser um [problema XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/499/132).

Comment: @Isac Não é um canhão para matar mosca. É uma solda elétrica para matar uma mosca. Ou seja: Uma ferramenta totalmente inadequada para o trabalho.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Sim seria mais correto ver dessa forma

Comment: É possível, mas ficará extensa e chata. Farei em cima da definição: múltiplo de 400, ou então múltiplo de 4 mas não de 100

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Fazer matemática com expressões regulares é algo terrível.

Comment: eu tenho programas em c++ que valida mas queria aprender e entender como fazer somente pela regex como ficaria pois se nao estou enganado em outras linguagens acho que teria como mas meu foco é fazer isso usando o c++...

Comment: @VictorStafusa eu sei, por isso a parte do "extensa e chata@. Poderia por tediosa também

Comment: @dark77 Aprender a usar regex também concerne em saber que tipo de trabalho elas não são capazes de fazer ou são uma péssima escolha. Regex não é uma boa resposta a este problema.

Comment: sim é uma pésima escolha mas seria mesmo pra entender e aprender como ficaria usando somente a mesma...

Comment: @dark777 Eu percebo o que diz em relação a tentar aprender. A minha opinião é que isto é tão longe do contexto real de uma regex que acaba por não aprender muito, porque grande parte não será aplicável noutros contextos. Acho que se torna bem mais produtivo e fácil de aprender com outros exemplos realistas e uteis de regex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319295/date-leap-year-validation-regex isso pode te ajudar.

Comment: @dark777 respondi. Muito mais matemática do que regex. Não tem como fugir. Procure outra alternativa para estudar regex de modo menos matemático, como reconhecer emails

Comment: ja fiz uma regex pra validar emails até criei um topico aqui e a regex que encontrei pesquisando no google era absurdamente grande cheia de coisas que na minha opnião se faziam desnecessárias entao fui mechendo até encurtar ela e validar nos formatos que eu precisava ficou show de bola... O tópico é este: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182756/express%c3%a3o-regular-para-e-mail-em-c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Você tem a arma, eu te dou a munição, mas você quem decide se deve atirar na própria perna ou não.
>
> Venho aqui lhe oferecer a regex que reconhece anos bissextos, não faz tudo como a resposta do @VictorStafusa. Minha regex também não tem *lookahead*, então isso tende a deixá-la mais longa

Primeiro, definição de ano bissexto:

> ano múltiplo de 400, ou então se é múltiplo de 4 mas não de 100.

Tendo em mente que estamos lidando com números representados decimalmente. Vou simplificar aqui e assumir que todo ano tem 4 dígitos. Isso significa que `720` não é possível, mas `0720` é.

Um múltiplo de 400 é um múltiplo de 4 qualquer seguido de `00`. Então, preciso de uma expressão que detecte múltiplos de 4 de dois dígitos. Um número é múltiplo de 4 de 2 dígitos (ou mais) na base 10 se:

1. Terminar com um número par
2. Se o dígito das unidades for múltiplo de 4, o das dezenas precisa ser par
3. Se o dígito das unidades for não múltiplo de 4, então o das dezenas precisa ser ímpar

Então, temos a seguinte expressão para reconhecer múltiplos de 4:

```
[02468][048]|[13579][26]
```

Para reconhecer múltiplos de 400, basta por `00` no final:

```
([02468][048]|[13579][26])00
```

Para ser múltiplo de 4 mas não de 100, é basicamente aquela primeira expressão, mas o `0` das dezenas é um caso especial, pois só aceita `4` ou `8`:

```
[2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48]
```

Para ignorar os primeiros dígitos:

```
..([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])
```

Juntando tudo:

```
([02468][048]|[13579][26])00|..([2468][048]|[13579][26]|0[48])
```

Answer (score 5):

Bem, regex não são uma boa alternativa para este problema. Pois esse é um problema matemático e regex não sabem fazer contas, elas apenas avaliam repetições em strings.

Entretanto, como um exercício de curiosidade, vamos usar regex mesmo assim.

Primeiro, comecemos com algo que reconheça um número de 01 a 28 (dias que têm em todos os meses):

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])
```

Algo que reconheça um número de 01 a 12:

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

Juntando os dois:

```
(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])
```

Para os meses com 30 ou 31 dias:

```
(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:01|0[3-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31\/(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12))
```

Algo que reconheça números de anos a partir de [1583](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calend%C3%A1rio_gregoriano):

```
(?:[2-9][0-9]{3}|1[6-9][0-9]{2}|159[0-9]|158[3-9])
```

Juntando tudo:

```
(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:01|0[3-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31\/(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)))\/(?:[2-9][0-9]{3}|1[6-9][0-9]{2}|159[0-9]|158[3-9])
```

Essa foi a parte fácil. Isso reconhece todos os dias que não sejam 29 de fevereiro.

Nos dias que são 29 de fevereiro, o dia e o mês são fáceis:

```
29\/02
```

Os últimos dois dígitos de anos que sempre são bissextos:

```
(?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])
```

Assim, esses anos não terminados em 00 são bissextos:

```
(?:[2-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|1[6-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|159(?:2|6)|158(?:4|8))
```

Esses são os anos desde 1583 terminados em 00 e bissextos:

```
(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00
```

Combinando-se isso, chega-se a todos os 29 de fevereiros desde 1583:

```
29\/02\/(?:(?:[2-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|1[6-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|159(?:2|6)|158(?:4|8))|(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)
```

Combinando-se todos:

```
(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])\/(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:29|30)\/(?:01|0[3-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31\/(?:01|03|05|07|08|10|12)))\/(?:[2-9][0-9]{3}|1[6-9][0-9]{2}|159[0-9]|158[3-9])|29\/02\/(?:(?:[2-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|1[6-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|159(?:2|6)|158(?:4|8))|(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)
```

Comment: Eu propus um jeito mais simples de se detectar anos bissextos. Menos coisas a se digitar, creio que vai dar uma expressão mais simples para a sua resposta, que está bem mais completa do que a minha

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Obrigado. Apliquei a simplificação.

Comment: @Jefferson Quesado eu dei uma olhada neste link que foi passado nos comentarios acima: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319295/date-leap-year-validation-regex dei uma mechida na regex tentando entender a mesma e cheguei ao seguinte resultado: std::regex pattern("^(?:\\d{4}[*-. /](?:(?:(?:(?:0[13578]|1[02]|Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec)[*-. /](?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0|1]))|(?:(?:0[469]|11|Apr|Jun|Sep|Nov)[*-. /](?:0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:0[2]|Feb[*-. /](?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))|(?:(?:\\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?:(?:[02468][048])|[13579][26])00)[*-. /]Feb[*-. /]29)$");

Comment: com a regex acima consigo validar os formatos: 1904-Feb-29, 1904*Feb*29, 1904.Feb.29, 1904/Feb/29 porem estou tentando fazer com que a mesma faça 1904/02/29 ainda nao consegui assim que der certo vou me basear nas suas explicaçoes para fazer o contrario: 29/02/1904, 29-02-1904,29.02.1904,29*02*1904...

Comment: @dark777 Quais formatos você quer afinal? Esse daqui só aceita DD/MM/YYYY, onde todos eles são numéricos. Construir uma regex para os outros formatos, ou mesmo que aceite todos os formatos, não é muito difícil, mas você tem que dizer quais são os formatos que importam.

Comment: Indiferente pois a minha intenção mesmo era: dd/mm/yyyy na regex acima adcionei outros formatos a serem validados como dd-mm-yyyy etc. A regex acima ela valida yyyy/mm/dd  portando o formato seria indiferente se a pessoa usar 1904/02/29; 1904/Feb/29; 1904-February-29 1904-02-29; 1904-Feb-29; 1904-February-29 agora eu tenho que entender como fazer ao contrario pois 29/02/1904; 29/Feb/1904; 29/February/1904;29-02-1904; 29-Feb-1904; 29-February-1904

Comment: Deu certo agora dei uma estudada nelas e fiz esta regex pattern("(?:(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])[*-. /](?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:29|30)[*-. /](?:01|0[3-9]|1[0-2]))|(?:31[*-. /](?:0[13578]|1[0-2])))[*-. /](?:[2-9][0-9]{3}|1[6-9][0-9]{2}|159[0-9]|158[3-9])|(?:(?:(29[*-. /]02[*-. /]:?))(?:(?:\\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][04‌​8]|[13579][26]))|(?:‌​(?:[02468][048])|[13‌​579][26])00)))$");

Comment: @dark Uma data do tipo "11/10-2017" é válida?

Comment: Não ja percebi isso estou mechendo nela pra modificar.