# Regex para validar determinado formato de data

Tags: c++, string, regex

Estava modificando uma regex para um programa em c++ que que validar o seguinte formado de entrada das datas `29/feb/2000`. Atualmente ela estava aceitando somente `29/02/2000` ou `30/03/2017`.

Tentei adicionar para os outros meses mas nao estou conseguindo. Como fazer para que seja possivel `30/mar/2017` ou `20/dec/2018`?

Segue a regex:

```
"^(?:(?:0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8])(?:/|.|-)(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])|(?:(?:29|30)(?:/|.|-)(?:0[13456789]|1[0-2]))|(?:31(?:/|.|-)(?:0[13578]|1[02])))(?:/|.|-)(?:[2-9][0-9]{3}|1[6-9][0-9]{2}|159[0-9]|158[3-9])|29(?:/|.|-)(?:02|feb|Feb)(?:/|.|-)(?:(?:[2-9](?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|1[6-9](?:(?:04|08|[2468][048]|[13579][26])00)|159(?:2|6)|158(?:4|8))|(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)$"
```

Comment: O Boost possui umas bibliotecas interessantes, sugiro utilizá-las para validação: [Format Date Parser](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#io_objects.format_date_parser). Porque Regex precisaria de algo mais complexo para validar por exemplo: `29/02/2018` ou `29/02/2020`. Em que o primeiro é inválido e o segundo válido.

Comment: As observações feitas nas respostas [desta sua outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245172/64969) se aplicam aqui, conforme o próprio Jsbueno ressaltou

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Regex definitivamente não é a ferramenta certa para resolver este problema. No entanto, li nos comentários que você está estudando regex... Então, só por diversão

#### Regex

```
^(?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|j(?:an|u[nl])|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec|feb)|(29|30)([-/.])(0?[13-9]|1[0-2]|j(?:an|u[nl])|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)|(31)([-/.])(0?[13578]|1[02]|jan|ma[ry]|jul|aug|oct|dec))(?:\2|\5|\8)(0{2,3}[1-9]|0{1,2}[1-9]\d|0?[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})|(29)([-/.])(0?2|feb)\12(\d{1,2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0?[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])00))$
```

⟶       ⟶       ⟶       ⟶         ⟶         ⟶           ⟶                 ⟿                     **∞**

Vamos ver o [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/xVhik3zVmXVNkEdc) para desenrolar:

[image: Debuggex]

Ou explicado com variáveis:

```cpp
std::string regexData() {
    std::string
        sep                = "/",

        dia1a28            = "(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])",
        dia29              = "(29)",
        dia29ou30          = "(29|30)",
        dia31              = "(31)",

        mesFev             = "(0?2|feb)",
        mes31diasNum       = "0?[13578]|1[02]",
        mes31diasNome      = "jan|ma[ry]|jul|aug|oct|dec",
        mes31dias          = "("+mes31diasNum+"|"+mes31diasNome+")",
        mesNaoFevNum       = "0?[13-9]|1[0-2]",
        mesNaoFevNome      = "j(?:an|u[nl])|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec",
        mesNaoFev          = "("+mesNaoFevNum+"|"+mesNaoFevNome+")",
        mesTudoNum         = "0?[1-9]|1[0-2]",
        mesTudoNome        = mesNaoFevNome+"|feb",
        mesTudo            = "("+mesTudoNum+"|"+mesTudoNome+")",

        diames29Fev        = dia29+sep+mesFev,
        diames1a28         = dia1a28+sep+mesTudo,
        diames29ou30naoFev = dia29ou30+sep+mesNaoFev,
        diames31           = dia31+sep+mes31dias,
        diamesNao29Feb     = "(?:"+diames1a28+"|"+diames29ou30naoFev+"|"+diames31+")",

        ano001a9999        = "(0{2,3}[1-9]|0{1,2}[1-9]\\d|0?[1-9]\\d{2}|[1-9]\\d{3})",
        anoX4nao100        = "\\d{1,2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])",
        anoX400            = "(?:0?[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])00",
        anoBissexto        = "("+anoX4nao100+"|"+anoX400+")",

        dataNao29Fev       = diamesNao29Feb+sep+ano001a9999,
        data29Fev          = diames29Fev+sep+anoBissexto,

        dataFinal          = "(?:"+dataNao29Fev+"|"+data29Fev+")";
    return dataFinal;
}
```

**Usando diferentes separadores de data**

Pode usar algo como:

```cpp
^(dia)[-/.](mês)[-/.](ano)$
```

```cpp
dia = match[1]; mes = match[2]; ano = match[3];
```

Mas isso permitiria uma data como `1.2/2000`.

Para forçar uma coincidência usando o *mesmo* separador, deve usar um grupo para pegar o primeiro e, no segundo, usar um [retrovisor](http://aurelio.net/regex/guia/retrovisor.html#2_4_4) (*[backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html)*) para coincidir com o texto capturado por esse grupo:

```cpp
^(dia)([-/.])(mês)\2(ano)$
```

```cpp
dia = match[1]; mes = match[3]; ano = match[4];
```

---

#### Código

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main() {
    constexpr char text[]{"29/feb/2020"};
    std::regex re(R"((?:(?:(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-/.])(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|j(?:an|u[nl])|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec|feb)|(29|30)([-/.])(0?[13-9]|1[0-2]|j(?:an|u[nl])|ma[ry]|a(?:pr|ug)|sep|oct|nov|dec)|(31)([-/.])(0?[13578]|1[02]|jan|ma[ry]|jul|aug|oct|dec))(?:\2|\5|\8)(0{2,3}[1-9]|0{1,2}[1-9]\d|0?[1-9]\d{2}|[1-9]\d{3})|(29)([-/.])(0?2|feb)\12(\d{1,2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:0?[48]|[13579][26]|[2468][048])00)))");
    std::cmatch match;
    bool valid = std::regex_match(text, match, re);

    if (valid) {
        std::cout << "Data válida: " << match[0] << std::endl
                  << "Dia: " << match[1]  << match[4]  << match[7]  << match[11] << std::endl
                  << "Mês: " << match[3]  << match[6]  << match[9]  << match[13] << std::endl
                  << "Ano: " << match[10] << match[14] << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Data inválida!!";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Resultado

```
Data válida: 29/feb/2020
Dia: 29
Mês: feb
Ano: 2020
```

[Exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/tKs6ai)

Comment: Interessante mas nao entendi pq vc usou "constexpr char text"ao invés de "const char text"? testei sua regex e ela esta validando formatos como 29-02.2000 ao invés de somente ser 29/02/2000 ou 29-feb-200 ou 29.2.200 tentei algo como [-|/|.] mas mesmo assim continua validando 29-02.2000..

Comment: eu tinha tentado algo parecido tambem com isso coloquei a sua sugestão e mesmo assim nao deu certo ainda continua validando: do mesmo jeito. 
O meu codigo é este: https://pastebin.com/uztcDi7J

Comment: @dark777 Porque você não está usando uma [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) para o segundo separador. Veja a diferença em que usei `(?:\2|\5|\8)` e `\12` no meu padrão

Comment: entao eu tentei sem o backreferense e mesmo assim nao deu certo. ([-/.]) tentei usar assim tambem (?:[-/.]) ou ([-|/|.]) ou (?:[-|/|.])e mesmo assim nenhum deles deu certo.

Comment: @dark777 Talvez eu não estivesse suficientemente claro. Você DEVE usar uma backreference. Este é o seu código, editado com o regex correto: https://wandbox.org/permlink/nlctMLXJaGUFfNdu (e verifique as correções em `print()`)

Comment: caraca coisinha chata de se entender, faz tempo já que estava pesquisando como resolver este problema alem de algums outros na mesma agora esta tudo certo obrigado pela ajuda e atenção..

Answer (score 1):

Enquanto que seja possível fazer isso por meio de expressões regulares, eu não acredito que seja o melhor caminho em qualquer linguagem de programação. 
(Não sei por que cargas d'água respondi a pergunta achando que era de Python também - mas a maior parte da resposta, exceto o código exato do exemplo, se aplica)

Nomes de meses vão ser bem mais fáceis de checar, verificar, e sobretudo - "pegar o número do mês", para ter um objeto `date` real se você verificar esses nomes de mês por fora da expressão regular.

Igualmente se sua aplicação em algum momento for funcionar em outra língua além do português: há frameworks para transformar programas em programas multi-lingua, e em geral eles dependem de você colocar todas as strings de seu programa dentro de uma chamada de função (muitas vezes com um nome destinado a ser quase transparente como `_()`). Essa funçao então busca sua string na língua desejada na base de traduções. Se os nomes dos meses estiverem hardcoded dentro da expressão regular, você teria que passar a regexp inteira para o engine de tradução.

Claro que seria possível montar um template da expressão regular, com os nomes dos meses em variáveis externas, e juntar tudo usando interpolação de strings, antes de se chamar a função de expressões regulares - isso é uma das vantagens de em Python expressões regulares serem utilizáveis através de chamadas de função normais, sem ter uma sintaxe especial.

Mas expressçõe regulares já são bem difíceis de ler e manter em código. Expressões regulares alteráveis em runtime seriam ainda mais complicadas de ler.

A minha dica, como no primeiro parágrafo, seria usar a expressão regular para obter os grupos com dia, mês e ano, e em seguida, um mecanismo mais tranquilo, com dicionários e if's para extrair o "mês real".
E aproveitar esse ensejo, para fazer a validação de dias do mês, ano, e etc...também fora do contexto da expressão regular. Vou colocar um exemplo em Python, que é um ótimo pseudo-código para C++  - mas você vai poder ter uma ideia do problema:

Então, em vez de:

```
def validate_date(text):
    if re.search(super_complicated_auto_validating_regexp, text):
        return True
    return False
```

É possível escrever algo como:

```
short_months = {"jan": 1, "fev": 2,...,"dez": 12}

def days_per_month(month, year):
    data = {1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4:30, ...}
    if month == 2 and year % 4 == 0 and (not year % 100 == 0 or year % 400 == 0):
            return 29
    return data[month]

def parse_date(text):
    match = re.search(r"(\d{1,2})/(.{1,3})/(\d{2,4})", text)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError("Invalid date format")
    day, month, year = [match.group[i] for i in (1,2,3)]
    day = int(day.lstrip("0"))
    if not month.isdigit():
       month = short_months[month.lower()]
    month = int(month.lstrip("0"))
    year = int(year):
    if year < 50:  # assume 2 digit years < 50 are in XXI
          year += 2000
    elif year <= 99:  
         year += 1900
    if day > days_per_month(month, year):
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid day {day} for month {month}")
    result = datetime.date(year=year, month=month, day=day)
```

Perceba que são necessárias mais ou menos 20 linhas de código programático para fazer o parsing  e a validação da data. Com a abordagem que você tem de expressão regular, você quer comprimir toda  a lógica dessas 20 linhas em uma única 'linha', que na verdade é um mini-programa numa linguagem que não é amigável a manutenção.

Dito tudo isso, a forma mais normal de se fazer parsing e validação de datas "reais" nos vários formatos loucos que usuários possam digitar, ou estar em arquivos, é usar uma biblioteca especializada para isso. Nela, várias pessoas, durante centenas de horas, já deram uma pensada em como tornar a coisa mais amigável e mais a prova de erro - você teria que duplicar esse trabalho no seu código (com chances de fazer errado - veja a sutileza para calcular corretamente anos bissextos - que até a microsoft errou nas primeiras versões do Excel, por exemplo)

Em Python, temos a excelente [dateparser](http://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), que permite que você faça simplesmente:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse("25/fev/2018", languages=["pt"])

datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 25, 0, 0)
```

Ela permite muitos outros formatos de data do que o separado por /, inclusive datas escritas por extenso em mais de 20 línguas - e não é propensa a erros por conta de "corner cases".

Em C++ eu buscaria por módulos complementares de data de algum framework que você já poderia estar usando para prover mais funcionalidades à linguagem - deve haver "natural date parsers" usando Qt ou Boost, por exemplo.

Comment: A pergunta está rotulada com [tag:c++].

Comment: é - nem sei por que resondi como se fosse Python. A maior parte do texto em português se aplica no entanto - infelizmente não o exemplo de código. Vou manter a resposta, adicionadas as ressalvas.

Comment: Respostas, mesmo que em linguagens divergentes da requisitada, são bem vindas. Imagina se eu pegar um problema semelhante em Python? Ou não ter um compilador C++ disponível para fazer um código para reconhecer datas? A propósito, gostei muito da resposta

Answer (score 1):

> validar o seguinte formado de entrada das datas 29/feb/2000 [...]

Se você quer validar somente o formato de entrada tente essa regex de validação:

```
\d{2}\/[a-zA-Z]{3}\/\d{4}|\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}
```

Porém se você quer fazer uma validação que aceite somente os meses do ano, sugiro que você não use regex, tente fazer uma comparação na entrada do dia e mês analisando se é igual as entradas permitidas (Se for esse o caso, comente que posso modificar a resposta).

---

**Explicação**

Valida se a sequencia for:

- 2 Dígitos
- 1 /
- 3 Caracteres de a até z
- 1 /
- 4 Dígitos
  Ou
- 2 Dígitos
- 1 /
- 2 Dígitos
- 1 /
- 4 Dígitos

[Você também pode ver um exemplo dessa regex funcionando aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/L0OFqp/1/)

Comment: interessante mas como estou estudando a std::regex do c++ estava tentando fazer isso com ela, tenho uma que faz a verificação doa anos bisextos e aceita de  2000/jan/30 a 2000/dec/30 ou 2000/01/30 a 2000/dec/30 ela faz verificação de anos bisextos corretamente mas valida yyyy/mm/dd estava tentando fazer o contrario para validar dd/mm/yyyy consegui mas agora precisava inserir os as strings dos meses nela.

Comment: @dark777 entendi, então você quer validar os meses agora? validar somente meses como jan, fev, mar, abr? Você pode usar varios "|" (ou's) aninhados na regex, porém ela vai virar um monstro de grande kkkk