# Forçando backreference em regex

Tags: c++, regex

Estes dias atras perguntei aqui sobre uma regex que valida datas e como forçar os separadores a regex validava o seguinte formato: *dd/mm/yyyy*

Então com base nela estava tentando forçar os separadores usando backreference em uma regex que valida os formatos: *yyyy/mm/dd* mas nao estou conseguindo alguém poderia me explicar como encontrar os valores para o backreference e fazer isso? A regex que preciso forçar os backreferences que valida *YYYY/mm/dd* é esta.

```
R"(^(?:\d{4}([-/.])(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|j(?:an|ul)|[Mm]a[ry]|[Aa]ug|[Oo]ct|[Dd]ec)([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]))|(?:(?:0?[469]|11|[Aa]pr|[Jj]un|[Ss]ep|[Nn]ov)([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:(0?2|[Ff]eb)([-/.])(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))|(?:(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?:(?:[02468][048])|[13579][26])00)([-/.])(0?2|[Ff]eb)([-/.])29)$)"
```

Comment: Independente da resposta correta, eu não acho que validar datas nesse nível seja algo legal de implementar como uma expressão regular. Escrevi bastante sobre isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/272541/500

Comment: amigo, me desculpe mas não entendi. Pode exemplificar as entradas e as validações?

Comment: @Paz a regex valida a seguinte entrada de dados: yyyy/mm/dd ou seja 2000/02/29 ou 2000/feb/29 ou 2000/Feb/29 porem como estou usando separadores diferentes preciso forçar com backreference pois a regex esta validando a seguinte entrada: 2000/02-29 ou 2000/feb.29 ou 2000-Feb.29 quando deveria validar somente com algums dos separadores...

Comment: @jsbueno com base no que vc disse la eu estava tentando forçar com o backreference mas nao entendi muito bem como encontrar os valores ou entender os grupos para determinar os valores das backreferences... To ligado que nao é a melhor solução estou estudando regex por questoes de topico de um livro que um professor passou pra mim quando estava fazendo na facul o mesmo é de C porem como estou estudando c++ entao busquei estudar a std::regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Minha resposta complementa a [resposta do Paulo R. F. Amorim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/279551/68989), mostrando como o que ele disse é aplicado a Expressão Regex colocada na pergunta.

Veja que numa Regex você cria os Grupos através dos parênteses, o que está dentro de parênteses será capturado pelo grupo; e, cada Grupo possui um id numérico para que possamos referenciá-lo. O id `0` corresponde ao match da regex inteira; podemos saber os ids dos Grupos dentro da expressão regex observando a ordem - da esquerda para direita - em que os parênteses são abertos:

Na Regex `a(b|c)(apartamento|ca(sa|rro))`:

1. o Grupo de id `1` é `(b|c)` que retornará `b` ou `c`;
2. o Grupo de id `2` é `(apartamento|ca(sa|rro))` que retornará `apartamento` ou `casa` ou `carro`;
3. o Grupo de id `3` é `(sa|rro)` que retornará `sa` ou `rro` *(ou será indefinido se o grupo de id `2` contém `apartamento`)*.

Se você quiser que um Grupo não tenha uma referência, ou seja, um id, você pode usar `(?:)` que cria um *non-capturing group*, com explicado [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138179/7711016) do SOen (em inglês).

A sua Regex começa assim: `(^(?:\d{4}([-/.])...` Veja que o Grupo `([-/.])` possui o id `2`, pois antes dele temos um *non-capturing group* `(?:\d{4}...` e um Grupo de id `1` que é aberto pelo primeiro parêntese`(^...`.

O Separador da data pode ser obtido pelo id `2` que é a referência do Grupo "`([-/.])`", que retornará `-` ou `/` ou `.`. Para fazer referência a esse grupo basta fazer `\2` como o @Paulo explicou.

Atualmente sua Regex apresenta várias vezes Grupos iguais a "`([-/.])`", nós podemos simplesmente manter o primeiro desses (que tem id `2`, como expliquei acima) e substituir os outros pela referência dele que é `\2`; eu decidi manter a referência dentro de Grupos para facilitar, de modo que, temos um Antes/Depois assim:

Antes:  `(^(?:\d{4}([-/.])...([-/.])...([-/.])...([-/.])...`
Depois: `(^(?:\d{4}([-/.])...(\2)...(\2)...(\2)...`

Com isso, a Regex só dará match se todos os separadores forem iguais ao capturado pelo Grupo de id `2`, de modo que só validamos datas que não misturam separadores diferentes. Então haverá match em uma data como `2000/02/28`ou `2000-02-28`, mas não haverá match numa data como `2000/02-28`.

No fim, sua Regex fica assim:

```
(^(?:\d{4}([-/.])(?:(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02]|j(?:an|ul)|[Mm]a[ry]|[Aa]ug|[Oo]ct|[Dd]ec)(\2)(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]))|(?:(?:0?[469]|11|[Aa]pr|[Jj]un|[Ss]ep|[Nn]ov)(\2)(?:0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|30))|(?:(0?2|[Ff]eb)(\2)(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-8]))))|(?:(?:\d{2}(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26]))|(?:(?:[02468][048])|[13579][26])00)([-/.])(0?2|[Ff]eb)(\7)29)$)
```

Note que, no final da expressão eu utilizei uma referência ao Grupo de id `7` ao invés do grupo de id `2`: `...(\7)29)$)`; isso foi necessário devido à características específicas da sua Regex, que dá um tratamento diferente para os dias 29 do mês fevereiro. Isso fica mais claro no [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/P90LP4sPYoHChlkp):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja na imagem que não daria certo fazer o `Group 9` (`Ref 4`) referenciar o `Group 2` porque o `Group 2` estará *indefinido* quando a data é do dia 29 de fevereiro, mas, fazemos o `Group 9` referenciar o `Group 7` que não estará indefinido nas datas do dia 29 de fevereiro.

Answer (score 2):

A idéia do backreference no Regex é que você possa reutilizar um bloco através do grupo criado por ele. Por exemplo:

Nesse regex `([a-c])x\1x\1` fica definido como grupo 1 o seguinte bloco `([a-c])`, que define que é a letra "a", "b" ou "c".

Então são válidos nesse caso as seguintes palavras "axaxa", "bxbxb" ou "cxcxc" como está bem explicado nesse [link](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html). O site https://regexr.com/ é uma ferramenta útil para identificar o grupos e validar o regex.

Comment: isso eu entendi o que eu nao entendi é como encontrar os valores para o backreference e colocar na regez para que funcione pois tenho a seguinte regex aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/272539/regex-para-validar-determinado-formato-de-data/273720#273720 e a mesma esta validando com backreference os separadores mas ao modificar ela para a regex acima recebendo ano/mes/dia nao estou conseguindo entender a como achar os valores dos backreferences..