# Expressão regular 6 casas decimais

Tags: regex

Alguém me saber dizer se é possível criar uma expressão regular com as seguintes características:

- valor entre 31.000000 e 43.000000
- o valor pode ter 6 casas decimais, mas deve estar no intervalo de 31 a 43.

O que eu tenho é o seguinte:

```
^(\+|-)?(\d\.\d{1,6}|[1-6]\d\.\d{1,6}|1[1-7]\d\.\d{1,6}|43\.0{1,6})$
```

é possível definir um valor minimo?

Comment: Precisa ser regex? Dependendo da linguagem, é possivel que já tenha algum recurso mais simples do que regex.

Comment: eu trabalho com formulários online e só posso criar as regras por regex ou então por regras de validação. se não der para fazer por regex tento criar por regras de validação que me digam se o valor é >31 e <43

Comment: mas pediram-me para tentar fazer por regex primeiro

Comment: Sem tempo agora, mais dá uma melhorada aqui: `^[3-4]{1}+[0-9]{1}.?[0-9]{6}$`. Primeiro caractere 3 ou 4 + Segundo caractere entre 0 e 9 o ponto separando, após a interrogação é opcional 6 dígitos entre 0 e 9

Comment: Formulário online? HTML? Se sim, JavaScript está aí para salvar sua vida. Só não se esqueça que é preciso fazer a validação a nove de servidor também, que validação a nível de cliente é só para melhorar a experiência de uso, mas não pode ser usado como única maneira de verificação/validação.

Comment: O intervalo é aberto ou fechado? Nos comentários está escrito que os valores extremos não devem pertencer ao intervalo

Comment: @PauloRicardo Há alguns erros na sua Regex: **1** `{1}` não é quantificável por `+`. **2** `.` o ponto final corresponde qualquer caractere e não `/.` o ponto literalmente e o `?` corresponde a 0 ou 1, porém deve haver ponto. **3** Valores como 47.000000 e 30.000000 são aceitos pela lógica de regex utilizada.

Comment: @danieltakeshi, não deixei como resposta pois já sabia que haveria erros, tentei deixar só um ponto de partida, no intuído de ajudar apesar de esta "engatinhando" com Regex, Mais obrigado pelo alerta, já estou exercitando o uso da classe, para entender um pouco melhor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não é o caminho ideal, mas tendo que ser:

```
^((3[1-9]|4[0-2])(\.\d{0,6})?|43(\.0{0,6})?)$
```

Comment: Obrigada. Já consegui fazer :D

Answer (score 11):

Concordando com todas as ressalvas que uma validação via expressão regular não é o caminho, podemos divagar no assunto.

> Não custa lembrar, só porque você **pode** fazer, não quer dizer que **deve** fazer.
>
> Vou repetir o aviso que coloquei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/245176/64969), porque não custa nada alertar:
>
> > Você tem a arma, eu te dou a munição, mas você quem decide se deve atirar na própria perna ou não.

A [resposta do @JJoao](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/276063/64969) trata de intervalos fechados. Eu li que em [seus comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276043/express%C3%A3o-regular-6-casas-d%C3%A9cimais#comment564205_276043) você cita que o intervalo é aberto. Então, pondero, como deveria ser para intervalos abertos?

Vamos falar aqui primeiramente em intervalos unitários, depois extrapolamos para um intervalo qualquer.

### Aberto no limite superior

O primeiro caso é se o limite superior for aberto. Por exemplo, o intervalo `[42, 43)` aceita o valor `42.999999`, mas não `43.000000`.

Para reconhecer esse intervalo, com seis casas decimais, não tem segredo algum. Só extrapolar a ideia do @JJoao para o número desejado.

```
42(\.[0-9]{1,6})?
```

Essa expressão é fechada no limite inferior é aberta no superior. Aceita de `42` a `42.999999`, assim como `42.0000`, mas não aceita `43`.

### Aberto no limite inferior

E no limite inferior? Foi fácil no limite superior, será que também será no inferior?

Para isso, precisamos reconhecer qualquer string depois do `.` que contenha pelo menos um número diferente de zero, limitado a 6 números.

Basicamente essa é a mesma pergunta de gerar uma string de 1 a 6 dígitos em que pelo menos um desses dígitos seja diferente de zero. Consegui isto para responder, não consegui simplificar. Eu separei as alternativas abaixo, a resposta seria colocar elas todas intercaladas com `|`.

```
[1-9][0-9]{0,5}
0[1-9][0-9]{0,4}
0{2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3}
0{3}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}
0{4}[1-9][0-9]{0,1}
0{5}[1-9]
```

De certo modo, para um total de `m` casas decimais no máximo, começando com `z` zeros a esquerda, a fórmula de criação dessas subexpressões é:

```
0{z}[1-9][0-9]{0,m-z-1}
```

Sendo que `0 <= z <= m - 1`, com `z` e `m` inteiros não negativos.

Então, para reconhecer um número no intervalo aberto inferior (e apenas inferior), a regex seria um tanto quanto grande. Para `(42,43]`, seria:

```
42\.([1-9][0-9]{0,5}|0[1-9][0-9]{0,4}|0{2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|0{3}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0{4}[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|0{5}[1-9])|43(\.0{1,6})?
```

Já se fosse aberto em ambas as extremidades, a expressão não precisaria considerar o inteiro `43` ao final:

```
42\.([1-9][0-9]{0,5}|0[1-9][0-9]{0,4}|0{2}[1-9][0-9]{0,3}|0{3}[1-9][0-9]{0,2}|0{4}[1-9][0-9]{0,1}|0{5}[1-9])
```

### Unindo intervalos consecutivos

Bem, começamos com intervalos unitários, que começam em números inteiros. E como seria a união desses intervalos caso eles sejam consecutivos?

A primeira alternativa seria colocar as expressões de cada intervalo agrupadas entre `(` parentes `)` e intercaladas com `|`.

Mas, poderíamos fazer melhor, não é?

O intervalo mais bem comportado é o intervalo fechado no limite inferior porém aberto no limite superior. Ele contém uma parte constante (a parte inteira do número) seguida da seguinte expressão:

```
(\.[0-9]{1,6})?
```

Quando estamos intercalando diversos desses intervalos, basta colocar essa expressão do lado direito e por do lado esquerdo as constantes separaras por `|` ou alguma outra expressão que remeta a isso. Por exemplo, `[32,43)` pode ser representado assim:

```
(3[2-9]|4[0-3])(\.[0-9]{1,6})?
```

Do lado direito, a expressão mágica que representa o intervalo unitário fechado no limite inferior porém aberto no superior. Do lado direito, uma expressão que representa todos os inteiros no intervalo passado.

Caso seja necessário lidar com um intervalo fechado no limite superior, basta adicionar o valor limite seguido de 0 a 6 zeros. Como se fosse uma união entre o intervalo fechado no começo porém aberto no final e do número individual: `[42,43) U {43}`

```
42(\.[0-9]{1,6})?|43(\.0{1,6})?
```

As outras uniões podem continuar sendo aplicadas normalmente, então fazer `[32, 43]` é fazer `[32,42) U [42,43) U {43}`:

```
(3[2-9]|4[0-3])(\.[0-9]{1,6})?|43(\.0{1,6})?
```

Para intervalo aberto, entretanto, a fórmula vai ficar grande. Não vou por como ficaria a expressão aqui, ela seria ilegível de qualquer sorte. O pensamento, entretanto, seria isolar um único intervalo unitário aberto em ambas as extremidades, então tratar o resto como intervalos fechados no limite inferior e aberto no superior. Tipo, `(32,43]` pode ser interpretado como `(32,33) U [33,43]`, ou então como `(32,33) U [33,43) U {43}`.

Comment: Obrigada! Ajustei ao que era pretendido e consegui. (Também tinha de fazer para um intervalo negativo).

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta e pela explicação. Fiquei a perceber muito melhor as expressões regulares

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado, gostei de sua resposta, ate pelo fato de querer dar o máximo de informações possíveis, contudo creio que você complicou mais do que necessitava. Geralmente as coisas são mais simples do que parecem. Mesmo assim muito bem :D

Comment: excelente Jefferson, esclareceu algumas duvidas que tinha.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, responder sempre, simplificar nunca, e complicar preferencialmente =D Só estou lembrando aqui da pergunta que fizeram sobre reconhecer anos bissextos com regex