# Fazendo data munging com python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, data, datetime

Sejam os seguintes formatos de datas:

```
042555

04/25/1955

Abril 25, 1955
```

Como utilizar regex para transformar um formato de data em cada um dos outros (seriam 6 transformações)?

Por exemplo:

```
Entrada: 042555

Saída: 04/25/1955 e  Abril 25, 1955
```

Eu fiz:

```
import re
#re.sub(padrão, string)

ex1 = "04/25/1955"

pattern1 = r"\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}"

print(f"macth :{re.findall(pattern1 ,ex1)}")

ex2 = "042555"

pattern2 =r"\d{1,2}\d{1,2}\d{2}"

print(f"macth : {re.findall(pattern2 ,ex2)}")


ex3 = "April 25, 1955"
pattern3 = r"[A-Za-z]{2,}\s\d+,\s\d{4}"

print(f"macth : {re.findall(pattern3 ,ex3)}")
```

Comment: Precisa fazer usando Regex?

Comment: @Augusto Vasques: De preferência... MAs agradeço se mostrar outras soluções também...

Comment: Eu incluí [abaixo uma solução](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443422/112052) com regex e outra sem (e digo que a solução sem regex é melhor, e na resposta explico os motivos) :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Se quer trabalhar com datas, não use regex, use uma API de datas.**
Datas são mais complexas do que parecem e possuem regras difíceis de validar somente com uma expressão regular.

Por exemplo, você usou `\d{1,2}`, que aceita qualquer valor entre 0 e 99, então o programa aceitará erroneamente datas inválidas como "00/99/0000". Mas os meses só podem ser de 1 a 12, e eles podem ter 28, 29, 30 ou 31 dias. Para fevereiro é pior ainda, porque a quantidade de dias depende do ano ser bissexto ou não. Todas essas verificações podem até serem feitas com regex, mas ela ficará tão complicada que não vale a pena (só para ter uma ideia, veja alguns exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/245172/112052)).

E para o nome do mês você usou `[A-Za-z]{2,}`, que vai aceitar **qualquer** combinação de 2 ou mais letras (ou seja, não vai aceitar somente meses válidos, mas sim qualquer coisa, como "abc" ou "xyz"). Nesse caso é [relativamente fácil fazer uma regex que só aceite nomes de meses válidos](https://regex101.com/r/bi7v9r/1/), mas ainda sim você precisa combinar com as outras regras já citadas (quantidade máxima de dias, ano bissexto, etc).

---

Em Python você pode usar o [módulo `datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) para converter a string para uma data, e em seguida convertê-la de volta para strings em outros formatos. Basta usar os [formatos disponíveis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes).

No seu caso, uma solução seria:

```
from datetime import datetime

texto = '04/25/1955'
formatos = [ '%m%d%y', '%m/%d/%Y', '%B %d, %Y' ]
formato_encontrado = None
for formato in formatos:
    try:
        data = datetime.strptime(texto, formato)
        formato_encontrado = formato
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass # formato não corresponde à string, nesse caso não faço nada

if formato_encontrado is not None: # se encontrou um formato, converte a data para os outros formatos
    for formato in formatos:
        if formato != formato_encontrado:
            print(datetime.strftime(data, formato))
```

Eu crio uma lista com todos os formatos possíveis, e tento converter o texto para data, usando [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime). Se o texto não corresponde ao formato, é lançado um [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ValueError) e nesse caso não estou fazendo nada (mas você pode tomar alguma decisão ali no bloco `except`, como imprimir o erro ou tomar a ação que quiser) e tentando o próximo formato.

Se o formato foi encontrado, eu converto a data para os outros formatos, usando [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime). A saída do código acima é:

```
042555
April 25, 1955
```

**Mas atenção! Ainda tem alguns detalhes para acertar.**

---

Para o primeiro caso, que tem o ano com 2 dígitos (55), você quer que o ano seja 1955. Mas [segundo a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html), valores entre 0 e 68 são mapeados para os anos 2000 a 2068, e valores entre 69 e 99 são mapeados para os anos 1969 e 1999. Ou seja, o código acima converte "042555" para 25 de abril de **2055**.

Neste caso, você deve estabelecer uma data de "corte" para considerar se ela está no século 20 ou 21. Por exemplo, se eu quiser que valores acima de 50 estejam em 1900, bastaria fazer algo como:

```
def year_2to4_digit(two_digit_year, pivotyear = 1950):
    century = (pivotyear // 100) * 100
    if century + two_digit_year > pivotyear:
        return century + two_digit_year
    return century + 100 + two_digit_year

...
if formato == '%m%d%y':
    data = data.replace(year = year_2to4_digit(data.year % 100))
```

Ou seja, valores entre 51 e 99 seriam convertidos para os anos entre 1951 e 1999. Os demais valores (0 a 50) estariam entre 2000 e 2050. Se quiser outra "data de corte", basta mudar o parâmetro `pivotyear` na função `year_2to4_digit` (código baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53682578) do SOen, e nesse link você também encontra outras opções).

Já para o nome do mês, no seu código, o texto de entrada tem o mês em inglês ("April"), mas você disse que quer a saída em português. Por padrão, o Python usa os nomes em inglês, então você precisa usar o [módulo `locale`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html) para mudar o idioma:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')
```

Se tanto a entrada quanto a saída devem estar no mesmo idioma, você pode setar o *locale* uma vez no início do programa. Mas se a entrada está em inglês e a saída em português, uma alternativa seria setar o *locale* somente para `strftime`, e em seguida resetá-lo para a configuração original (para não afetar o restante do programa, por exemplo). O código completo fica assim:

```
from datetime import datetime
import locale

def year_2to4_digit(two_digit_year, pivotyear = 1950):
    century = (pivotyear // 100) * 100
    if century + two_digit_year > pivotyear:
        return century + two_digit_year
    return century + 100 + two_digit_year

texto = '042555'
formatos = [ '%m%d%y', '%m/%d/%Y', '%B %d, %Y' ]
formato_encontrado = None
for formato in formatos:
    try:
        data = datetime.strptime(texto, formato)
        formato_encontrado = formato
        if formato == '%m%d%y':
            data = data.replace(year = year_2to4_digit(data.year % 100))
        break
    except ValueError:
        pass # formato não corresponde à string, nesse caso não faço nada

if formato_encontrado is not None: # se encontrou um formato, converte a data para os outros formatos
    for formato in formatos:
        if formato != formato_encontrado:
            if formato == '%B %d, %Y': # mudar para o locale português
                locale_original = locale.getlocale(locale.LC_ALL)
                locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8')
            print(datetime.strftime(data, formato).capitalize())
            if formato == '%B %d, %Y': # voltar para o locale padrão
                locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, locale_original)
else:
    print(f'{texto} não corresponde a nenhum dos formatos aceitos')
```

Saída:

```
04/25/1955
abril 25, 1955
```

No meu caso, a saída em português foi "abril 25, 1955", ou seja, o nome do mês com letra minúscula. Essa configuração depende do *locale*, mas você pode fazer algo como:

```
print(datetime.strftime(data, formato).capitalize())
```

Que a saída será "Abril 25, 1955". No caso de números, o [método `capitalize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize) não faz diferença, pois dígitos não possuem uma versão "maiúscula" e não são alterados.

Vale lembrar também que para o caso do nome do mês em português, você deve ter o respectivo *locale* instalado no seu sistema, conforme explicado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/385217/112052).

---

#### Se quer mesmo usar regex

Uma solução seria:

```
import re

regex_dia = r'(?:0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])'
regex_mes = r'(?:0[1-9]|1[0-2])'
regex_ano = r'(?:19|20)\d{2}' # aceita apenas anos entre 1900 e 2099
regex_ano2 = r'\d{2}' # ano com 2 dígitos
# mês em texto
regex_mes_txt = '(?:Jan|Febr)uary|Ma(?:rch|y)|April|Ju(?:ne|ly)|August|(?:Octo|(?:Sept|Nov|Dec)em)ber'
# ou, se quiser em português
#regex_mes_txt = '(?:jan|fever)eiro|ma(?:rç|i)o|abril|ju[ln]ho|agosto|(?:(?:set|nov|dez)em|outu)bro'

def get_parser(*regexes, sep='', sep2=''):
    if sep2:
        exp = f'({regexes[0]}){sep}({regexes[1]}){sep2}({regexes[2]})'
    else:
        exp = sep.join(map(lambda s: f'({s})', regexes))
    r = re.compile(f'^{exp}$')
    def parse(texto):
        m = r.match(texto)
        if not m:
            return None
        return m.group(1, 2, 3)
    return parse

parsers = [
    get_parser(regex_mes, regex_dia, regex_ano2, sep=''),
    get_parser(regex_mes, regex_dia, regex_ano, sep='/'),
    get_parser(regex_mes_txt, regex_dia, regex_ano, sep=' ', sep2=', ')
]

# nomes dos meses em português
meses_pt = ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
# nomes dos meses em inglês
meses_en = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

formatters = [
    lambda dia, mes, ano: f'{mes}{dia}{int(ano) % 100}',
    lambda dia, mes, ano: f'{mes}/{dia}/{ano}',
    # pode trocar para meses_en se quiser o mês em inglês
    lambda dia, mes, ano: f'{meses_pt[int(mes) - 1]} {dia}, {ano}'
]

def year_2to4_digit(two_digit_year, pivotyear = 1950):
    century = (pivotyear // 100) * 100
    if century + two_digit_year > pivotyear:
        return century + two_digit_year
    return century + 100 + two_digit_year

texto = '042555'
formato_encontrado = -1
for i, parser in enumerate(parsers):
    dados = parser(texto)
    if dados is not None:
        mes, dia, ano = dados
        formato_encontrado = i
        if i == 0:
            ano = year_2to4_digit(int(ano))
        elif i == 2:
            mes = f'{meses_en.index(mes) + 1:02d}'
        break

if formato_encontrado >= 0: # se encontrou um formato, converte a data para os outros formatos
    for i, formatter in enumerate(formatters):
        if i != formato_encontrado:
            print(formatter(dia, mes, ano))
else:
    print(f'{texto} não corresponde a nenhum dos formatos aceitos')
```

Mas além de ficar bem mais complicado, esta solução deixa passar várias datas inválidas, como 31 de abril ou 29 de fevereiro em anos não bissextos (e nos links já indicados acima você viu como uma regex para validar essas coisas é bem complicada).

O exemplo acima foi só para mostrar que mesmo um exemplo incompleto e limitado fica mais complicado do que se usar a API de datas (que além de deixar o código mais simples, ainda valida todos os casos que a regex não consegue detectar). Novamente, reforço: se quer trabalhar com datas, use uma API de datas. [Regex nem sempre é a melhor solução](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/).