# Comparar datas - Text Mining

Tags: python, data

Fiz um código para texte mining, porém estou com dificuldade para comparar se a data que foi identificada já se passou + de 1 ano. Gostaria de uma ajuda ou uma visão que pode ajudar no meu entendimento.

```
import re
from pprint import pprint
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl import Workbook

caminho = './amostra.xlsx
arquivo_excel = load_workbook(caminho)
planilha = arquivo_excel['Plan1']

for row in planilha.values:
    # VERIFICA O TIPO (J OU F)
    if(type(row[1]) is str ):
        tamanho_j = row[52] == 'J' and len(row[83]) <= 250
        tamanho_f = row[52] == 'F' and len(row[83]) <= 100

        if(tamanho_f or tamanho_j):
            # VERIFICAR SE TEM DATA ( aqui no caso está minha dúvida para comparar a data)
            result = re.search(r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}', row[83])
            if(result != None):
                    #VERIFICA AS PALAVRAS CHAVES
                if (row[83] in ['Visitado', 'Visitada','Fachada', 'Fachadas', 'Box', 'instalações' ,
                 'instalação','instalada', 'instalado','estoque', 'funcionários', 'funcionário','layout']):
                        print(row[83])
                else:
                    print("não há palavras")
            else:
                print("SEM DATA")      
        else:
            print("ACIMA DOS CARACTERES")




        if(type(row[2]) is str):            
            tamanho_j = len(row[84]) <= 100
            tamanho_f = len(row[84]) <= 50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que tem em `row[83]`?

Se for **exatamente** a data no formato "dd/mm/aa" e nada mais, então nem precisa de regex, pode fazer o *parsing* diretamente:

```
from datetime import datetime

data = datetime.strptime('15/03/20', '%d/%m/%y')
hoje = datetime.now()
if (hoje - data).days > 365:
    # já se passou 1 ano
```

Um detalhe é que o ano está com 2 dígitos, e a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/time.html) diz que valores entre 0 e 68 são mapeados para os anos 2000 a 2068, e valores entre 69 e 99 são mapeados para os anos 1969 e 1999. Se quiser mudar esta regra, veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/443422/112052) (na parte que fala como mudar o *pivot year*).

---

Agora, se `row[83]` tiver um texto, e no meio dele tem uma data, aí faz mais sentido usar regex:

```
import re
from datetime import date

texto_contendo_data = 'abc 15/03/19 123 bla'
match = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})', texto_contendo_data)
if match:
    dia, mes, ano = map(int, match.groups())
    d = date(2000 + ano, mes, dia)
    if (date.today() - d).days > 365:
        # já se passou 1 ano
```

Eu considerei que o ano com 2 dígitos sempre se refere ao século 21 (ou seja, ano "10" refere-se a 2010, ano "90" é 2090, etc). Também usei [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#date-objects) em vez de [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects), pois aqui só temos o dia, mês e ano, e o horário não parece importar no cálculo da diferença.

Se a regex encontrou uma data no formato indicado, eu transformo os trechos encontrados em números, usando [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) e [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), e em seguida uso esses valores numéricos para construir a data (não precisa construir uma string só para fazer o *parsing* de novo, pode criar a data diretamente a partir dos valores encontrados).

Repare que a regex possui parênteses: eles formam [grupos de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), que eu posso recuperar depois com o [método `groups`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.groups). Como eu sei que são 3 grupos, já posso atribuir o valor diretamente para as variáveis `dia`, `mes` e `ano`.

Lembrando que a regex vai encontrar quaisquer números, então se tiver "99/99/99" no texto, ela tenta criar esta data. Claro que você pode usar uma regex mais elaborada se quiser ([veja algumas opções aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/363711/112052)), mas de qualquer forma, `strptime` pode dar erro se a data for inválida. Se quiser validar isso também, coloque o código dentro de um bloco `try`/`except`:

```
try:
    # tenta criar a data aqui dentro
except ValueError as e:
    # erro ao criar a data
    print(e) # se quiser imprimir a mensagem de erro para saber o que aconteceu
```

Comment: No row[83] seria a coluna da onde eu quero que fizesse a mineração no texto e encontrar a data, por isso utilizei o regex no caso, só não estava conseguindo fazer essa verificação se passou mais de 1 se passou para realizar o teste. Mas obrigado!

Comment: date.today vs datetime.now da documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.now em um exemplo sem o TZ é praticamente o mesmo, mas não vejo pq importar 2 módulos diferentes, a não ser que for depender de algo a mais no módulo date (me refiro apenas ao seu primeiro código)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento  É, eu achei que considerar ou não o horário poderia dar diferença (pois há casos em que faz), mas para esse caso específico não faz porque a data a ser lida não tem o horário então sempre será meia-noite. Alterei o primeiro código, obrigado!

Comment: Sim, isto de horas não falei explicitamente, mas foi o que eu já havia respondido, 365 não vai ser um ano todo de fato, não só pela falta de horas informadas, mas pelo simples fato que a cada ano podem haver variações de segundos e minutos e até outras variações, então no caso é só 365 baseado a partir do que é informado e nem tem como forçar o script a viver de adivinhações ;)

Answer (score 1):

Usando a função https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime para fazer o "parse" da data recebida

E use o https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects para checar a diferença de anos em uma comparação de **dois** `datetime`

Vale lembrar que seu ano tem apenas 2 dígitos, o que é ruim, prefira sempre usar o ano cheio, 4 dígitos (se houver humanos até o ano de 10.000 ai será 5 digitos :) ) e use o `result.group(0)`

Deve ficar assim:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

result = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})', row[83])

if(result != None):
    ano = result.group(0)

    data_atual = datetime.strptime(ano, "%d/%m/%y")

    if (datetime.now() - data_atual).days > 365:
        print("A data tem mais de um ano")
    elif (row[83] in ['Visitado', 'Visitada','Fachada', 'Fachadas', 'Box', 'instalações' ,
     'instalação','instalada', 'instalado','estoque', 'funcionários', 'funcionário','layout']):
            print(row[83])
    else:
        print("não há palavras")
```

Confira seus arquivos, porque se o ano já for completo então SEU script está errado e a regex deveria ser com o numero 4 no ultimo grupo:

```
 r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})'
```

Se tiver quatro digitos, troque o `%y` em minusculo por `%Y` em maiúsculo

Vale lembrar 365 não é bem um ano todo, talvez seja mais, depende muito de entender como funciona o calendário, mas isto é um pouco complicado de explicar

---

Um exemplo de comparação simples para teste seria isto:

```
from datetime import datetime

import re

# Com 2 digitos em ano

data_inserida = "teste 15/03/20 teste"

result = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{2})', data_inserida)

fulldate = result.group(0)

data_atual = datetime.strptime(fulldate, "%d/%m/%y")

if (datetime.now() - data_atual).days > 365:
   print("mais de um ano", fulldate)
else:
   print("menos de um ano", fulldate)

# Com 4 digitos em ano

data_inserida = "teste 15/03/2010 teste"

result = re.search(r'(\d{2})/(\d{2})/(\d{4})', data_inserida)

fulldate = result.group(0)

data_atual = datetime.strptime(fulldate, "%d/%m/%Y")

if (datetime.now() - data_atual).days > 365:
   print("mais de um ano", fulldate)
else:
   print("menos de um ano", fulldate)
```

Teste online: https://repl.it/@inphinit/how-old-is-a-date

Comment: Entendi, perfeito. Obrigado!

Comment: Caro @pauloalmansa testa primeiro com calma, acabei de corrigir o primeiro código, copia ele novamente e teste, então me avisa se esta tudo ok ou não.

Comment: Peguei o conceito e consegui implementar, é que na verdade o arquivo lê um arquivo em excel e ele checa se existe a data. Se for maior de 1 ano que estiver registrado, não vai passar no teste e vai me retornar o erro. Caso seja dentro de 1 ano, ele passa para os próximos testes. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @pauloalmansa blz, marca a resposta como correta por favor.

Comment: @fernandosavio foi vestigios da primeira resposta, que não removi, obrigado. Já editei.

Comment: @fernandosavio estava distraído, só agora reparei, group(0) já resolvia tudo sem precisar concatenar, ajustei pra simplificar